# How to pass elements in a for loop to parent component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, components, v-for

**Background** I have a child component that loops through an array called "expenseButton" passed from my parent component. Within this for loop are elements that are getting updated. Specifically the *"expense"*.

**Child component**

```
<form class="container">
      <div class="buttonList" v-for="(expense, index) in expenseButton" :key="index">
        <button type="button" @click="expenseButtonClick(expense)">{{expense.expensesKey}}</button>

        <input class="textInput" v-model.number="expense.subExpense" type="number" />

      </div>
</form>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    expenseButton: Array,
  },
  methods: {
    expenseButtonClick(expense) {
      expense.expensesValue = expense.expensesValue - expense.subExpense;
    }
}
}
</script>
```

**Problem** I understand that $emit events can pass data to the parent.  However, I am trying to figure the best way to send the updated **elements** of the array back to the parent component.

**The Parent component data**

```
<template>
<expense-button :expenseButton="expenseButton"></expense-button>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {
    "expense-button": Expenses
  },
  data() {
    return {
      expenseButton: [    
{"expensesKey":"rent","expensesValue":null,"subExpense":""},
{"expensesKey":"movies","expensesValue":null,"subExpense":""},
{"expensesKey":"clothes","expensesValue":null,"subExpense":""}
],
    };
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use $emit.
Child component:

```
<form class="container">
      <div class="buttonList" v-for="(expense, index) in expenseButton" :key="index">
        <button type="button" @click="expenseButtonClick(expense)">{{expense.expensesKey}}</button>

        <input class="textInput" v-model.number="expense.subExpense" type="number" />

      </div>
</form>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    expenseButton: Array,
  },
  methods: {
    expenseButtonClick(expense) {
      expense.expensesValue = expense.expensesValue - expense.subExpense;
      this.$emit("expense-btn-clicked", expense)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Parent component:

```
<template>
  <expense-button :expenseButton="expenseButton" @expense-btn-clicked="btnClickedHandler"></expense-button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {
    "expense-button": Expenses
  },
  data() {
    return {
      expenseButton: [    
        {"expensesKey":"rent","expensesValue":null,"subExpense":""},
        {"expensesKey":"movies","expensesValue":null,"subExpense":""},
        {"expensesKey":"clothes","expensesValue":null,"subExpense":""}
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    btnClickedHandler(e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I get that part but how would the parent  tell which object would get updated? the "expense" property being sent in the $emit is just an iteration of the "expenseButton" for loop

Comment: @EddieWeldon because when it enters in expenseButtonClick(expense), `expense` is emited to the parent. `expense` being an element of the `expenseButton` array. Example: `{"expensesKey":"rent","expensesValue":null,"subExpense":""}`

Comment: Got it! Thanks alot